# How can merging on a wider p dataframe (n, p) can take more time?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, merge

I observe longer computation runtime when merging a dataframe with more columns. But the number of links to make remains unganged. Does someone has an insight on the reason of this behaviour ?

Here is the code :

```
def set_vars(n, p):
    np.random.seed(seed=42)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(27, size=(n,p)), columns=['merge'] + list(range(p-1)))
    df_merge = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((np.arange(26).reshape((26,1)), 
                                            np.arange(26).reshape((26,1))), axis=1), columns=['merge', 'val'])
    return df, df_merge

df, df_merge = set_vars(1000000, 5)

%%timeit
b = df.merge(df_merge, on='merge')
# 255 ms ± 63.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

df, df_merge = set_vars(1000000, 20)

%%timeit
b = df.merge(df_merge, on='merge')
# 494 ms ± 46.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Each row after the definition of `set_vars()` was run separately, so df and df_merge definition are not impacting.

Not sure to understand why. As the merge is on only one column, why having a big (p) dataset is impacting the performance ?

Answer (score 0):

`df.merge` creates a new dataframe. This operation is costly and *dependant of the size of the input dataframes and also the resulting dataframe*. In the first case, the size of the output dataframe `b` is `963224 x 6`, while in the second case, it is `963137 x 21`. Producing a ~3 time bigger dataframe takes about twice more time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't know that writing the dataset was this expensive.